# Parsing complex JSON Objects to Java Objects and adding to the recyclerview

Tags: android, json, gson

[onResponse(JSONObject response)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ndj7.png)I want to get the data from the server and parse it to the recycler view. I have seen many answers on stackoverflow but could not find any proper solution for my complex JSON data. I'm using volley library and may be the GSON is the proper way to map with my Java objects. Please tell me  the proper way of getting response from this json. I only want to use the information of "title","body" and "createdAt". Following is a part of my json that i'm recieving with the help of authorization Token.

```
{
"content": [
    {
        "id": "5c56e41245dfac0001100221",
        "createdAt": "2019-02-03T12:52:34.225+0000",
        "productName": "ams",
        "title": "WPB Plan hass been APPROVED",
        "body": "Dear Operator , WPB Plan Report Report has been Checked and Acknowledged.",
        "data": {
            "subModule": "wpb",
            "moduleName": "planning",
            "workspaceName": "Planing module ",
            "category": "wpb",
            "url": "http://pulse.target.meeraspace.com/ams/planning/wpb/details/5c56df5e2812a00001a23dc3",
            "taskId": "182951",
            "workspaceId": "360"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CiRlMTNjNDgxZC1iZDcwLTU0OTMtOWI1NS1kNjVhY2Q3OTM2MWQSBWxvY2Fs",
            "name": "hashim",
            "email": "hashim.shamsi@targetofs.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c56bba345dfac00011001fa",
        "createdAt": "2019-02-03T10:00:03.314+0000",
        "productName": "ams",
        "title": "WPB Plan hass been APPROVED",
        "body": "Dear Operator , WPB Plan Report Report has been Checked and Acknowledged.",
        "data": {
            "subModule": "wpb",
            "moduleName": "planning",
            "workspaceName": "Work Space Testing on EDGE Jan 2019",
            "category": "wpb",
            "url": "http://pulse.target.meeraspace.com/ams/planning/wpb/details/5c56b9182812a00001a23db9",
            "taskId": "182856",
            "workspaceId": "31"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CiRkODAyNWJhNy01ODJlLTU0NzktOTE4MS01MGE5ZTZmZGY3YWYSBWxvY2Fs",
            "name": "Rajesh M",
            "email": "rajesh.mhamunkar@targetofs.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c53e9f545dfac000110019f",
        "createdAt": "2019-02-01T06:40:53.558+0000",
        "productName": null,
        "title": "Workspace",
        "body": "invites you to workspace CSR",
        "data": {
            "workspaceId": "308",
            "workspaceName": "CSR",
            "moduleName": "workspace",
            "subModuleName": "base",
            "description": "Workspace invite",
            "url": "/workspace/details/308"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CiQ2MjIxY2FjZS05OGM4LTU5NWEtOTc2NS1kYTNiN2QyODM0ZTkSBWxvY2Fs",
            "name": "Usman Aleem",
            "email": "usman.aleem@targetofs.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c52c67945dfac0001100148",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-31T09:57:13.404+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "Jane",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c52c67945dfac0001100147",
            "workspaceId": "247"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c52c42945dfac0001100144",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-31T09:47:21.425+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "Jane",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c52c42945dfac0001100143",
            "workspaceId": "247"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c52c41e45dfac0001100140",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-31T09:47:10.714+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "Jane",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c52c41e45dfac000110013f",
            "workspaceId": "247"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4ff2eed669df00018df86d",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-30T11:40:36.997+0000",
        "productName": "workspace-message-345",
        "title": "you have 5 new messages",
        "body": "you have 5 new messages",
        "data": {
            "totalNotification": 5,
            "moduleName": "message",
            "workspaceName": "Testssfsdf",
            "message": [
                {
                    "channelId": "5c4fdcb2d669df00018df85d",
                    "type": "direct",
                    "unreadMessages": 4
                },
                {
                    "channelId": "5c500a58a20c78000129aaff",
                    "type": "group",
                    "unreadMessages": 1
                }
            ],
            "workspaceId": "345"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c510af6a20c78000129ab8c",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-30T02:24:54.276+0000",
        "productName": "workspace-message-351",
        "title": "you have 1 new message",
        "body": "you have 1 new message",
        "data": {
            "totalNotification": 1,
            "moduleName": "message",
            "workspaceName": "test-by-benjamin",
            "message": [
                {
                    "channelId": "5c4fdcb2d669df00018df85d",
                    "type": "direct",
                    "unreadMessages": 1
                }
            ],
            "workspaceId": "351"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4fdadad669df00018df858",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-29T04:47:22.035+0000",
        "productName": null,
        "title": "Workspace",
        "body": "invites you to workspace Testssfsdf",
        "data": {
            "workspaceId": "345",
            "workspaceName": "Testssfsdf",
            "moduleName": "workspace",
            "subModuleName": "base",
            "description": "Workspace invite",
            "url": "/workspace/details/345"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CiRhYjMyYzZmMS1hYjBhLTVhZjctOTFjYy04ODg1MDU3MTdkOGISBWxvY2Fs",
            "name": "Yuchao Lu",
            "email": "yuchao.lu@target-energysolutions.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4efdf3d669df00018df845",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-28T13:04:51.693+0000",
        "productName": "ams",
        "title": "Annual Base Report",
        "body": "Dear Operator ,  Annual Base report for Inventory has been checked and acknowledged.",
        "data": {
            "subModule": "base",
            "moduleName": "inventory",
            "category": "AnnualInventoryProcess",
            "url": "http://pulse.target.meeraspace.com/ams/inventory/base/details/5c4efdcb71306a0001d55c85",
            "taskId": "182281"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CglyZWd1bGF0b3ISBWxvY2Fs",
            "name": "Regulator",
            "email": "regulator@yopmail.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4efd3bd669df00018df83d",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-28T13:01:47.168+0000",
        "productName": null,
        "title": "Task Assignment",
        "body": "body",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "taskManager",
            "description": "DESC",
            "url": "/workspace/task-manager/126",
            "taskId": "649"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CiQxODFkYjU5ZS0wZGNjLTVkYmMtOWYxNi1lMjlkMjRiYTNjZTISBWxvY2Fs",
            "name": "Mohsin",
            "email": "targetmohsin@gmail.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4ef924d669df00018df833",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-28T12:44:20.780+0000",
        "productName": null,
        "title": "Task Assignment",
        "body": "body",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "taskManager",
            "description": "DESC",
            "url": "/workspace/task-manager/126",
            "taskId": "621"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CiQxODFkYjU5ZS0wZGNjLTVkYmMtOWYxNi1lMjlkMjRiYTNjZTISBWxvY2Fs",
            "name": "Mohsin",
            "email": "targetmohsin@gmail.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c49dc92d669df00018df73c",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-24T15:41:06.964+0000",
        "productName": "ams",
        "title": "WPB Plan",
        "body": "Dear TECOM members, WPB Plan Report has been submitted, please check and acknowledge.",
        "data": {
            "subModule": "wpb",
            "moduleName": "planning",
            "workspaceName": "test 1",
            "category": "wpb",
            "url": "http://pulse.target.meeraspace.com/ams/planning/wpb/details/5c49dc9071306a0001d55c44",
            "taskId": "180930",
            "workspaceId": "317"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CghvcGVyYXRvchIFbG9jYWw",
            "name": "Operator",
            "email": "operator@meerawork.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c49dc91d669df00018df739",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-24T15:41:05.757+0000",
        "productName": "ams",
        "title": "WPB Plan",
        "body": "Dear TECOM members, WPB Plan Report has been submitted, please check and acknowledge.",
        "data": {
            "subModule": "wpb",
            "moduleName": "planning",
            "workspaceName": "test 1",
            "category": "wpb",
            "url": "http://pulse.target.meeraspace.com/ams/planning/wpb/details/5c49dc9071306a0001d55c44",
            "taskId": "180923",
            "workspaceId": "317"
        },
        "from": {
            "sub": "CghvcGVyYXRvchIFbG9jYWw",
            "name": "Operator",
            "email": "operator@meerawork.com",
            "valid": true
        },
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c495629d669df00018df715",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-24T06:07:37.072+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "Android",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c495629d669df00018df714",
            "workspaceId": "126"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4635d6d669df00018df6ad",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T21:12:54.801+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4635d6d669df00018df6ac",
            "workspaceId": "314"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4635b5d669df00018df6aa",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T21:12:21.382+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4635b5d669df00018df6a8",
            "workspaceId": "314"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c46357ed669df00018df6a6",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T21:11:26.883+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c46357ed669df00018df6a4",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c463538d669df00018df6a0",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T21:10:16.935+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c463537d669df00018df69e",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4634ebd669df00018df69c",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T21:08:59.607+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4634ebd669df00018df69a",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4632abd669df00018df68d",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:59:23.197+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4632abd669df00018df68c",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c46327ad669df00018df689",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:58:34.525+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c46327ad669df00018df688",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c46322cd669df00018df685",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:57:16.298+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c46322cd669df00018df684",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4631c0d669df00018df67e",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:55:28.482+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4631c0d669df00018df67d",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c462ed4d669df00018df674",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:43:00.419+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c462ed4d669df00018df673",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c462ac0d669df00018df670",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:25:36.835+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c462ac0d669df00018df66f",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c462a87d669df00018df66d",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:24:39.704+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c462a87d669df00018df66b",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c46294dd669df00018df668",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T20:19:25.889+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c46294dd669df00018df667",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4624bbd669df00018df664",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T19:59:55.793+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4624bbd669df00018df663",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4623d3d669df00018df660",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T19:56:03.623+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4623d3d669df00018df65f",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c46234bd669df00018df65c",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T19:53:47.284+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c46234bd669df00018df65b",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c462296d669df00018df655",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T19:50:46.325+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c462296d669df00018df654",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c462234d669df00018df652",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T19:49:08.522+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c462234d669df00018df650",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4621cbd669df00018df646",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T19:47:23.114+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "First-workspace",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4621cbd669df00018df645",
            "workspaceId": "313"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4583139b09c60001a94445",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T08:30:11.922+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "test 1",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4583139b09c60001a94443",
            "workspaceId": "317"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4581679b09c60001a94440",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T08:23:03.482+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "test 1",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c4581679b09c60001a9443f",
            "workspaceId": "317"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
    {
        "id": "5c457ff09b09c60001a9443a",
        "createdAt": "2019-01-21T08:16:48.297+0000",
        "productName": "meetings",
        "title": "Meeting invitation",
        "body": "New meeting invitation",
        "data": {
            "moduleName": "meeting",
            "action": "popup",
            "workspaceName": "test 1",
            "category": "meeting invitation",
            "subModuleName": "invitation",
            "url": "/mp/api/v2/meetings/invitation/5c457ff09b09c60001a94439",
            "workspaceId": "317"
        },
        "from": null,
        "viewed": false
    },
```

Comment: create appropriate model class and use it with gson.

Comment: you can generate a pojo class for your json data and user that class for getting data

Comment: creating an appropriate pojo class ? That is a very basic thing. Its all completed from my side. I have an issue in my onResponse method. I couldn't figure out this thing. I know that my root is object{} so i couldn't use JsonarrayRequest. So how cann i implement JSONObject?

Comment: show  your `onresponse` method . and please add @myname . otherwise i wont get notified

Comment: Please review my post , I have added a link of my onResponse method. @TejasPandya

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class or classes(in your case) and parse them appropriately with Gson on your Volley onResponse method.

You can convert your JSON response to Java POJO classes online with this [link](http://jsonschema2pojo.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. In your `onResponse` method you are receiving `JSONObject` reponse . so add that object to your model class like this .

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
YourPOJOClass dataResponse = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), YourPOJOClass.class);
```

I'm assuming you have successfully generated your POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this online link to convert your [json to poja class](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). All you have to do create a nested pojo class and try **retrofit** not volley, it is outdated

I use like this

```
String temp = jsonString;
Gson gson = new Gson();            
Favourites favourites = gson.fromJson(temp, Favourites.class);
```

here my favourites is my master pojo class